# Removing rows in R dataframe based on the number of words in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to subset a data.frame in R based on the number of words in one column. There will only be one or two words (so the presence of a white space in the string could be used instead) - I want to keep rows with two words, and delete those with one.
For example, for df below, I want to keep rows 1,2,4 and 6.

```r
df <- data.frame(id = c("one one","one two","one","two one","two","two one"),
               data = seq(1:6))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `df[grep("\\s", df$id),]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the id's with a white space

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(id," "))
```